# Nginx and Wordpress: Add php after postname

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wordpress

I'm doing a migration from Apache to Nginx of some Wordpress sites.

Now I'm dealing with the URL rewriting, because one of the blogs has the following URL structure:

```
%postname%.php
```

And I'm using the following location block:

```
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

to do the rewrite for `%postname%`

How can I match for the last added .php ?

Thanks!

Comment: Besides being bad for SEO, that permalink structure is going to make your nginx configuration very difficult here. You really should get rid of it.

Comment: Hi! I'm looking exactly this: http://mygames.com/game-pet-rescue-facebook.php

Answer (score 0):

Despite the poor SEO... this might work (or loop)...

```
location ^~ /(.*)\.php$ {
  try_files /index.php?$1 =404;
}
```

Make sure to set the permalink settings in Wordpress correctly.

Comment: Hi! I can't get it working using this rewrite block :(